# How to set background image, that fit screen for ios splash screen version in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, image, flutter, splash-screen

There is task to make splashscreen with background image, that fit screen, and logo image in center. To make this splash screen for android - is done, but how make this for ios? Are there methods without two splashscreens for ios(flutter white splash screen and second IOS native screen in role of splash)?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**For iOS app**

Open flutter project on Xcode for Adding splash screen to flutter ios app. To open the iOS module on Xcode, open android studio and on the top menu select tools. Go to flutter –> open ios module on Xcode. [see example here](https://www.dripcoding.com/flutter-splash-screen/)

**On Xcode** window, Click on Runner-> Runner -> Assets.xcassets folder. Here you can see LaunchImage paste your splash screen image with all three different dimensions in this folder.

Open **LaunchScreen.storyboard** Again on the left side menu just below the Assets.xcassets folder, you will see LaunchScreen.Storyboard. Click on view controller scene -> view controller -> view. Note: – select (click on ) view only don’t click on LaunchImage. You already paste the new splash screen in the LaunchImage folder in the previous step. So you will see the same new image here in this window. When you select (click on ) view then on the right side window you can see options to change view settings like content mode, background, alpha etc. change the background colour as you want and set content mode to scale to fill. enter image description here

**Adjust Splash Screen** You can adjust the splash screen position, size & background colour on the same window. Just click on launchImage OR select the image on the preview window. You can resize the image and can adjust the image position. On the Right side window, you can make another setting as well.

iOS App Splash Screen is Ready. Now flutter white splash screen problem has been resolved successfully for both android and iOS. You can change the flutter splash screen background color as per your requirements.